# Is it possible to pass data to flutter app with click on link?

Tags: flutter

I need to pass data to the website and do something with that and return code as result to my flutter app through the link and continue operation on the app, but I do not know how to do it.
I am beginner in flutter!
please help me!

Comment: You need to provide more information, or review the documentation and tutorials for flutter.  What you are asking is overly broad and likely to receive downvotes.  Provide code samples and specifics.  You can try reading https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: thank for your answer. I need to open my flutter app from link in browser. for example i send an email for user and when click on link open my app and pass token to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Open flutter app from a link, We have to use Platform's url scheme. The procedure is as follows.

1. Add Url Scheme to Native environment.
2. Add the plugin for url scheme.
3. If you would like to get some string or number, you have to decode given url with regular expression.

I recommend you to start from iOS's implementation because it's more simple than Android's. Good Luck!!

#### How to add Url scheme.

for iOS

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

for Android

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

#### Plugin

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uni_links

#### Example of the implementation

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uni_links#-example-tab-